# Replacing values in pandas dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I want to create a new column that does a mapping. For example if col1 only contains Ted values then i want to make the mapping Ted, if it contains both Ted and Not Ted i want to make the mapping Both, if it only contains Not Ted values i want to make the mapping Not Ted.

I know how to do it for two conditions because i can just use np.where.. but it's more tricky because there's 3 conditions. How can i do this in python or pandas?

**input:**

```
col1
Ted, Ted
Ted, Not Ted
Not Ted, Not Ted
Not Ted, Ted
Ted, Ted
```

**expected output:**

```
col1                    new_col    
Ted, Ted                Ted
Ted, Not Ted            Both
Not Ted, Not Ted        Not Ted
Not Ted, Ted            Both
Ted, Ted                Ted
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html):

```
g = df['col1'].str.split(', *').explode().eq('Ted').groupby(level=0)

df['new_col'] = np.select([g.all(), ~g.any()], ['Ted', 'Not Ted'], 'Both')
```

Or:

```
s = (df['col1'].str.split(', *').explode()
     .groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: list(set(x)))
     )
df['new_col'] = s.str[0].where(s.str.len()==1, 'Both')
```

Or, with (frozen)set operations:

```
d = {frozenset(['Ted']): 'Ted', frozenset(['Not Ted']): 'Not Ted'}
df['new_col'] = [d.get(frozenset(x.split(', ')), 'Both') for x in df['col1']]
```

Output:

```
               col1  new_col
0          Ted, Ted      Ted
1      Ted, Not Ted     Both
2  Not Ted, Not Ted  Not Ted
3      Not Ted, Ted     Both
4          Ted, Ted      Ted
```

Comment: I always wanted to ask you this question: would there be any side effects if we used `set` instead of `frozenset` in the last approach ?

Comment: @Timeless give it a try! sets are not hashable ;)

Comment: Thanks mozway ;). It seems like I chose the wrong scenario to ask the question because sometimes the `dict`ionnary isn't part of the story. I'll let you know if I find a similar Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

With [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and *set operations* :

```
df["new_col"] = [
    set(lst).pop() if len(set(lst))<2 else "Both"
    for lst in df["col1"].str.split(",\s*")
]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

               col1  new_col
0          Ted, Ted      Ted
1      Ted, Not Ted     Both
2  Not Ted, Not Ted  Not Ted
3      Not Ted, Ted     Both
4          Ted, Ted      Ted
```

Comment: Nice one ;) I made a similar pandas version.

Comment: Thanks mozway ;), I tried to make it as simple as possible but can't garantee any speed awards though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda function to check that, and then use `apply` as shown below:

```
def check_values(s):
    if 'Ted' in s and 'Not Ted' in s:
        return 'Both'
    elif 'Ted' in s:
        return 'Ted'
    elif 'Not Ted' in s:
        return 'Not Ted'
    else:
        return np.nan  # for cases where none of the above apply

df['new_col'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: check_values(x.split(', ')))
```

Or you can use `np.where`:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('Ted') & df['col1'].str.contains('Not Ted'), 'Both',
                         np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('Ted'), 'Ted', 
                                  np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('Not Ted'), 'Not Ted', np.nan)))
```

Comment: Raising a ValueError for the last condition is a better practice I reckon, also mapping to a set would speed things up I reckon.

Comment: You don't need elif also because the previous conditions have a return endpoint

Comment: Numpy’s `select` function will let you make one call with multiple conditions in place of your nested `where` calls

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `.apply` to your dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Ted, Ted', 'Ted, Not Ted', 'Not Ted, Not Ted', 'Not Ted, Ted', 'Ted, Ted']})

def map_col1_to_col2(value):
    names = value.split(', ')
    if names[0] == 'Ted' and names[1] == 'Ted':
        return 'Ted'
    elif names[0] == 'Not Ted' and names[1] == 'Not Ted':
        return 'Not Ted'
    else:
        return 'Both'

df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(map_col1_to_col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with `str.get_dummies()`

```
d = df['col1'].str.get_dummies(sep=', ')

d.mul([1,2]).sum(axis=1).map(dict(enumerate(['Neither','Not Ted','Ted','Both'])))
```

Output:

```
0        Ted
1       Both
2    Not Ted
3       Both
4        Ted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# using dataframe already created by Seojin Kim
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Ted, Ted', 'Ted, Not Ted', 'Not Ted, Not Ted', 'Not Ted, Ted', 'Ted, Ted']})
print(df)

col1
0   Ted, Ted
1   Ted, Not Ted
2   Not Ted, Not Ted
3   Not Ted, Ted
4   Ted, Ted

df['col2']=df['col1'].apply(lambda x:','.join(set(i.strip() for i in x.split(','))))

print(df)

                col1                   col2
0           Ted, Ted                    Ted
1       Ted, Not Ted            Ted,Not Ted
2   Not Ted, Not Ted                Not Ted
3       Not Ted, Ted            Ted,Not Ted
4           Ted, Ted                    Ted
```